# How to "flatten" Serverless Framework directories when deploying lambda functions to AWS

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

### Developing an AWS lambda function...

### and deploying it using the Serverless Framework

service `serverless.yml` file:

```
service: user

frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  architecture: arm64
  region: ${opt:region, 'us-east-1'}
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'development'}

package:
  individually: true

functions:
  - ${file(./lambda/functions/authorizeUser/serverless.yml)}
```

function `serverless.yml` (in the relative directory referenced above)

```
authorizeUser:
  handler: index.handler
  name: authorizeUser
  description: Registers or Authorizes a user with the system

  package:
    patterns:
      - '!**/*'
      - ./lambda/functions/authorizeUser/index.js
      - ./lambda/functions/authorizeUser/magic.js
```

I need to use the directory in which the service `serverless.yml` file resides as the base path for the individual lambda function source `*.js` files. I originally expected that I could have just used the directory in which the function `serverless.yml` resides as the base path to the individual lambda function source `*.js` files. *How can I tell `sls deploy` to use the directory in which the function `serverless.yml` file resides as the base path to the individual lambda function source `*.js` files?*

But a bigger issue with my approach is that when the individual lambda function source `*.js` files are deployed on AWS the directory structure is recreated (e.g. the individual lambda function source `*.js` files land in my lambda function's):

`/authorizeUser/lambda/functions/authorizeUser`

directory which causes the following error when I test my lambda function:

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'index'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'index'",
    "Require stack:",
    "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:726:17)",
    "    at async Object.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:741:21)",
    "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:781:15",
    "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:4:1"
  ]
}
```

If I manually move the individual lambda function source `*.js` files to the `/authorizeUser` (the lambda function's root directory) the function will execute. *How can I tell `sls deploy` to flatten the directory structure when it deploys the lambda function to AWS (if this is even possible)?*

I realize that I can just place all of the files in the same directory in my development environment and these problems that I'm experiencing will not occur, but my preference is to manage source files in a nested directory structure to help categorize files into logic groups.

https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions

Answer (score 0):

I have come to the conclusion that flattening cannot be done because of the way that Serverless constructs the underlying CloudFormation template. Dropping to a parent directory (below the base directory) for the application services makes it impossible (or simply illogical from a purely computer science *tree* perspective) to attach sibling directories to the services. It would be helpful if there were documentation related to the way that Serverless "path" references are resolved and work together e.g., `glob` versus `$file()` references. If this exists somewhere, please send me a link.